# vsftp upload timeout on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, upload, timeout, vsftpd

I have set up VSFTPD on my Ubuntu 12.04. Nearly everthing is working fine. Connecting, authentication, retrieving directory listings, downloadings files. All works as expected. My problem is the file upload. Uploading a file with FileZilla ends up in a server timeout. FileZilla wants to reconnect and tries to store the file again on the server.

The interessting thing is, that the file upload did work very well. The file is stored correctly on the server!

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,253,162).
STOR phpinfo.php
150 Ok to send data.
```

After this I get the server timeout and FileZilla tries to reconnect. Do you think this points to problems with the passive mode configuration? Does this point to iptables and incoming ports for the passive mode (passive mode for i.e. directory listings work!)?

Here is my vsftpd.conf:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
nopriv_user=sites
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=sites
local_root=/var/www/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=12000
pasv_max_port=12010
```

I dont get it... Can anyone help me out?

Edit: Maybe I should have posted this question @ serverfault.com. Can someone move this question?

Answer (score 1):

Is filezilla in Active or Passive mode? I had a little trouble with vsftpd and how filezilla was transferring. I don't remember what the fix was but had something to do with how the files transferred.

http://flagrantdisregard.com/configuring-vsftpd-on-amazon-ec2/

Comment: I tried all three ways and set it explicit to Passive, Active and Standard. Made no diffrence...

Comment: Do you have filezilla to keep alive and stay connected?

Comment: Refering to your article I tested iptables with `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12000:12010 -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 12000:12010 -j ACCEPT`. Didnt work so far. How can I set up something like Keep-Alive in FileZilla?